# List of arguments with argparse

Tags: python, argparse

I'm trying to pass a list of arguments with argparse but the only way that I've found involves rewriting the option for each argument that I want to pass:

What I currently use:

```
main.py -t arg1 -a arg2
```

and I would like:

```
main.py -t arg1 arg2 ...
```

Here is my code:

```
parser.add_argument("-t", action='append', dest='table', default=[], help="")
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use [`nargs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#nargs):

> *ArgumentParser* objects usually associate a single command-line
>   argument with a single action to be taken. The *nargs* keyword argument
>   associates a different number of command-line arguments with a single
>   action.

For example, if `nargs` is set to `'+'`

> Just like `'*'`, all command-line args present are gathered into a list.
>   Additionally, an error message will be generated if there wasn’t at
>   least one command-line argument present.

So, your code would look like

```
parser.add_argument('-t', dest='table', help='', nargs='+')
```

That way `-t` arguments will be gathered into `list` automatically (you don't have to explicitly specify the [`action`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#action)).

Comment: perfect thank you, if i add nargs, i juste have to make action='store' and it works like a charm

Comment: @CondaKan `store` is the default action, you don't have to specify it explicitly

Answer (score 1):

Being aware, you asked for argparse solution, I would like to present alternative solution using package `docopt`

Install it first:

```
$ pip install docopt
```

Write the code:

```
"""Usage:
    main.py -a <arg>...
"""

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from docopt import docopt
    resargs = docopt(__doc__)
    print resargs
```

Run it to show usage instrucitons:

```
$ python main.py
Usage:
    main.py -a <arg>...
```

Call it with your parameters:

```
$ python main.py -a AA BB CC
{'-a': True,
 '<arg>': ['AA', 'BB', 'CC']}
```

Btw. if you do not need the `-a` option, you shall directly allow passing the arguments. It makes usage simpler to the user.